# Can I allocate more memory than I use

Tags: c, windows, memory, memory-management

I'm new to C programming and have been messing around with the memory management stuff. I have a couple of questions all relating to one scenario (I'll put the questions in bold). A simplified version of what I'm doing would be if I were to allocate 10 bytes (using malloc) of memory, but only use it to store an int (4 bytes)

**Will this cause issues on the memory side?**

**What happens to that extra memory?**

**Does it have to be manually freed or is there a way to do it automatically?**

**Should I just not bother messing around and just figure out the right size beforehand?**

Thanks for any help you give, it's really appreciated

Comment: 1. No, if you free it of course. 2. Nothing, it'll stay uninitialized (unless you use calloc) and if/when you free the memory, that extra mem will go too. 3. Manually use free(). 4. Use the amount of memory you need. If you think you need more later, allocate more. If you don't have enough but need more, use realloc.

Answer (score 1):

> Will this cause issues on the memory side?

Which side of what, and which side of it is the memory side?

It may use more memory than necessary.

> What happens to that extra memory?

It remains unused.

> Does it have to be manually freed or is there a way to do it automatically?

In a general-purpose operating system, the system will recover memory when your process terminates. If you want allocated memory to be available for reuse before that, you must free it.

> Should I just not bother messing around and just figure out the right size beforehand?

Appropriate strategies depend on circumstances. Some possibilities are:

- You allocate a large amount of memory, perform the operations to get data into it and then, having learned the size of the data, use `realloc` to release the excess memory.
- You make a fair estimate of the amount of memory needed, being sure to be at or over the requirement, not under, allocate that memory, and let the small excess be wasted.
- You allocate some memory and start operations to put data into it. As you acquire data, you watch for it filling the allocated amount. When more is needed, you use `realloc` to get more.

Comment: That cleared a lot of things up thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

For your purposes, the memory allocator doesn't know, nor does it really care about how much memory you actually use in a block you malloc. The key here is to never use *more* memory than you malloc. The extra memory just sits there, available for your use if you want it.

Note that allocating 10 bytes vs 4 bytes won't make much, if any difference for you, assuming you're not performing this allocation thousands of times.

The only validation / size calculation I'd recommend you never skip is ensuring that you never allocate too little memory for the item you're placing in the allocated space.

You don't technically have to free the memory (as the OS will clean up the mess you've made after your application exits), but you absolutely should. If you don't free memory after you're done using it, this is called a memory leak and will cause your application to use more RAM than it has to. Additionally, be very careful never to use memory again after you've freed it. That's called a use-after-free, and can be a dangerous bug.

Memory management in C is very much something you have to do manually, as opposed to some other languages.

Comment: That makes sense. I understood that memory management was important but I struggled and still am to find a source that explains it clearly to someone new to the language